# Create a field with record type values

Tags: record-type

Total Salesforce newbie. I have an Object with 3 record types. Want to create a field with a picklist "Record type 1", "Record type 2", "Record type 3". How do I reference record types when creating a field? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to create a Picklist that dynamically lists the record types? Or have varying values based on the record type? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I actually just figured it out -- used a formula field, formula = RecordType.Name. Thanks!